# Force a program to conform to Windows 7 window sizing ability?

Tags: windows-7, window, spotify

I use Spotify. Unlike just about every other Windows application, you can't slam it into the side of the screen to auto-resize it to fill that half of the screen. This is very irritating.

Is there any way to force it to have that ability? Some program you can run it inside of, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug (well, technically a "missing feature") of the Spotify client. The company is aware of the issue and there are at least two threads on the community forums about it. I would suggest upvoting them to draw more attention to them:

- http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Bug-Report-Windows7-window-resize-placement-hotkeys-do-not-work/td-p/105731
- http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Windows-desktop-app-does-not-resize-correctly/td-p/76423

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool named Plumb which provides automatic sizing/tiling of windows. It even has blacklist and whitelist and autosizing. Works in win7 and win8.

http://palatialsoftware.com/plumb/